# How to I translate cart page text in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation, shopping-cart, language-translation

Anyone know How to translate cart page text? I want to translate in German Language.Some of the text already translated but some are not.Please see attached image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B92y2_9HLLMHeWhRY01ITl9RRzQ/view?usp=sharing. Please please someone help me.

Thanks

Comment: I am relatively certain that WooCommerce is completely translated for German. Are you sure these aren't strings from your theme? You can switch briefly to Twenty Fourteen to verify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin like [WPML](https://wpml.org/) or translate it via .po/.mo files.

WooCommerce gives explanations on how to deal with it : http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-localization/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can I change the text via woocommerce files instead of translating

Comment: It's not advised because it could be erased at the next WooCommerce update.